# Cost of publishing iOS app outside of itunes

Tags: ios, itunes

If i create an ios app for that is published in app store i have to pay $99/year.  What if i don't want to publish it on the app store and just want to share it from my website, is there any type of licensing/registration fee for this?

Comment: You can't share it via your website. Without paying $99 you can only run an app in the simulator. Even if you pay $99 you can only give your app to 100 devices per year. This ignores jailbroken devices.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't publish through the App Store your only customers will be jail breakers - there is no fee for publishing for that audience.

If you don't feel your app will make enough to cover $99 in a year, you should perhaps consider a different business model.

If you're concerned about in-app purchases of physical items, then follow Till's advice (quoted from comment below):

> Apple does actually not allow for the payment of physical goods (like food) via iTunes - you will have to use a different payment option (like CreditCards) for such goods.

Comment: thanks for the quick replies.  The reason we were wanting to do this is because we want people to be able to order and pay for food from our iphone app without losing 30% to apple.

Comment: @Jeston you should really read the iTunes submission guidelines as well as the iTunes payment guidelines; to cut it short, Apple does actually not allow for the payment of physical goods (like food) via iTunes - you will have to use a different payment option (like CreditCards) for such goods.

Comment: Yeah, basically if it doesn't fall within the guidelines for in app purchases laid out [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html), which it sounds like it doesn't since you are selling food, then you must use your own payment method, which will not be subject to the 30% profit share.

Comment: @Till I've incorporated your comment into the answer and wikified it, hope that's ok.

Answer (score 0):

What you are paying for is essentially the distribution platform the App Store provides, which is pretty incredible. You also pay for the option of integrating other Apple features like iCloud, in app purchases and push notifications.

If you want to distribute the app outside of the App Store and want the same level of exposure, I'd guess that you'd be spending a whole lot more than $99/year. You can distribute your app through your website via Ad Hoc distribution (limited to 100 devices and really this is just for testing) or Enterprise distribution ($299/yr with no 30% cut or App Store distribution).

The cost/benefit is really in your favor to go with the App Store as far as distribution is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

What you should be looking into is a web-app.  You can tailor a web page in a lot of ways to look just like an app, then you can do whatever you like when the user visits your web site with an iPhone.